# Read barcode through a scanner hardware device and show scanned code in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I had searched and got so many tutorials to read bar code through iPhone camera using AVFoundation framework. But my requirement is to read the code through a hardware scanner device connected to iPhone via bluetooth. I had found ScanAPI but not working and also paid. Can anyone guide me, i am actively looking for solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need documentation for the hardware scanner manufacturer that describes how the scanned data is sent over Bluetooth. If you look for existing code and API, just look for plain Bluetooth code. How non-Bluetooth part is probably both simple and manufacturer specific.

Comment: If you want to use a hardware scanner, then you should start by specifying which scanner you're talking about. There's also probably documentation and/or an SDK that go with it...

Comment: Note that some scanners can just emulate a keyboard, in which case there would not be any development required.

Comment: We can't possibly help unless you specify which scanner you're using. If you haven't selected a scanner yet then I suggest you contact the different manufacturers and ask them about their development APIs for iOS. (This is usually called pre-sales tech support)

Comment: @jcaron can you please elaborate this "some scanners can just emulate a keyboard, in which case there would not be any development required". I can go with this solution. Please guide how to proceed.

Comment: @DuncanC My hardware scanner is of "Socket mobile" manufacturer.

Comment: Ok, and what do the docs say about APIs?

Comment: This is a case study in how **NOT** to ask a question. Vague, incomplete question, missing critical info, making people ask multiple questions to pull that critical info from you...

Comment: Socket mobile has different scanners which have different possibilities. AFAIR, some of them do have the keyboard emulation mode. In any case, there's plenty of documentation on their site, so that should have been your first stop.

Comment: Try : https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=barcode+scanner+swift

Answer (score 1):

I did a google search on SocketMobile and found that they have a 
[developer program](https://www.socketmobile.com/developers/welcome). I suggest you sign up for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Core BlueTooth documentation. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth?language=objc

Bluejay is a library used to simplify this, it might also help you.
https://github.com/steamclock/bluejay

I am doing this same task and I am starting with a Youthink Bluetooth Barcode scanner. Those are my starting points.

Comment: I know it's an old question but this came up pretty high in the google searches.